# Is there a way to Retrieve the ID of an Automation Instance via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automationstudio, instance

As far as I know the only way to link directly to a specific automation is with the Automation Instance ID (ex. https://mc.exacttarget.com/AutomationStudioFuel3/?hub=1#Instance/***MmdvcUZtcDhGa09rQXN2ZXlodmQ9ZzoyNTow***)

I'm attempting to create an Automation via the API and then immediately create a link to it, but I do not know of any way to retrieve the Instance ID. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the terminology of SFMC is a bit confusing. What they are calling 'instance id' or 'definition id' in this case is not the same as the ones we normally see or can access. It is basically just the 'internal' ID that SFMC uses on its objects and is not available externally. The only way I have seen to get access to this is via the internal API calls that SFMC uses in its UI - which requires a separate authentication and is not exposed to customers.

We are only shown the customer-facing ObjectID (with the dashes) which does not work as a replacement in the links and through available endpoints and objects cannot retrieve the required ID.

Another note, to help clarify is that the 'customer facing' Automation Instance ID is actually an object to represent a single run of an automation so you can get specific details about that specific run (See [LastRunInstanceID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automationinstance.htm)).  E.g. get start/complete time, get status, etc.

I unfortunately do not think there is the capability to build the links you want in an automated sense. It seems likely you will need to manually collect those IDs from the UI in order to complete your task. I sincerely hope someone else found a way around this as that would be a great capability if possible.

Comment: Thanks again Gortonington, you are a great asset to this community.